# How to create "short syntax" in PhpStorm to create file in Magento 2 (.xml, registration.php, ...)?

Tags: magento2

I have seen many videos on Youtube that use short syntax to create .xml files. (m2_registration, m2_module, ...). Or the code suggestion in Magento, but I can't find any related information.

I have trie to research "How to create short syntax in Magento 2" or "code suggestion in Magento 2". But i can't find any related information about my issue.

Thanks any tips??

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure this is related to your problem, but you can try this tool: https://mage2gen.com/

It would not create files in the IDE for you, but it would help you write them faster